# Use Port number for <sql:SqlDatabase> in wix

Tags: wix

I have a .wxs file which uses couple of  statements to create/drop/update the database. Also it has the 2  which is configured to WindowsAuthentication and SQL Authentication. Here I have a scenario where the Database server is configured at default DB port:1433 or non default port number. To make this work, I passed the port number in the below mechanism.

```
<sql:SqlDatabase Id="SqlMasterDBWinAuth" Server="[SQL_SERVER_NAME],[DATABASE_PORT]" Database="master" Instance="[SQL_INSTANCE_NAME]"/>
    <sql:SqlDatabase Id="SqlMasterDBSqlAuth" Server="[SQL_SERVER_NAME],[DATABASE_PORT]" Database="master" Instance="[SQL_INSTANCE_NAME]" User="SQLUser" />
```

This worked perfectly where the Database gets connected and created in the correct server name and at port number.

But during uninstallation of the product, I get the below error at UninstallSQLData.

```
===============================================================
Action 13:20:33: UninstallSqlData. Configuring SQL Server
Action start 13:20:33: UninstallSqlData.
MSI (s) (20:F8) [13:20:33:246]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Windows\Installer\MSI691A.tmp, Entrypoint: UninstallSqlData
UninstallCertificates:  Error 0x8007007a: Failed to copy server string to database object:MCC_HOME_DIRECTORY: C:\Program Files (x86)\NetIQ\DBManager\
AUTOSYNC_EXISTS: 0
DELETEDB: 
SQL_SERVER_NAME: BLRDVSMACHINE
SQL_INSTANCE_NAME: 
INSTALLDIR: C:\Program Files (x86)\NetIQ\DBManager\
REMOVE: ALL
DATABASE_PORT: 1433
,1433
UninstallCertificates:  Error 0x8007007a: failed to read SqlDatabase table
CustomAction UninstallSqlData returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
Action ended 13:20:33: UninstallSqlData. Return value 3.
===============================================================
```

Hence please let me know the below
1. Why is the uninstallation failing with the error?
2. Passing the Port number to the server Name parameter, a right approach?
3. Any other way to achieve this requirement of passing the Port number to the Server Name using SQL extensions?